# The "Ask Question" page shows a "question ban" page to suspended users instead of showing that the user is suspended

Tags: bug, asking-questions, post-ban, account-suspension

When I was suspended on MSE, I tried to [ask question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while being suspended. The page showed:

> [image: The wrong Ask Question page]

I think it should show the "You are suspended" page or something like that. Currently this page confuses the suspended users by saying that

> most of your questions need improvement or are out of scope for this site

I would suggest something like:

> You are suspended and can't post new questions right now.